# how to filter my database with only "Monday" queries?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to extract only monday from timestamp (in time,date,month format) in my database (would do count on it after wards). I tried to convert my dates to string characters. I was able to get all days in text format.

```
select to_char (payment_date, 'dy') as days from payment;
```

however, when i try to add where in it, to filter days, it gives an error.

```
select to_char (payment_date, 'dy') as days 
from payment 
where days.payment_date = 'mon';
```

Comment: `WHERE to_char(payment_date, 'dy') = 'mon'`

Comment: Thank you so so much. if you have time, can you kindly guide that "AS" executes at the end of the where etc. statement? because it seems so as your code is perfectly working. (I am currently learning sql)

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=78c733859589ee5d5eb60bb6f84ea069)):

Generate a table with all of the dates in the first half of 2022.

```
CREATE TABLE dat AS
SELECT the_day FROM GENERATE_SERIES 
  ('2022-01-01'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-06-30'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '1 DAY') AS t(the_day);
```

and then run:

```
SELECT
  the_day::DATE,
  EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM the_day),
   to_char(the_day, 'Day')
FROM
  dat
WHERE 
    EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM the_day) = 1;
```

Result:

```
the_day     extract     to_char
2022-01-03  1   Monday   
2022-01-10  1   Monday   
2022-01-17  1   Monday   
2022-01-24  1   Monday   
2022-01-31  1   Monday   
2022-02-07  1   Monday   
2022-02-14  1   Monday   
2022-02-21  1   Monday   
2022-02-28  1   Monday   
2022-03-07  1   Monday  
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

or similarly:

```
SELECT
  the_day::DATE,
  EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM the_day),
  to_char(the_day, 'DAY')
FROM
  dat
WHERE
  to_char(the_day, 'DAY') = 'WEDNESDAY';
```

Result:

```
the_day     extract     to_char
2022-01-05  3   WEDNESDAY
2022-01-12  3   WEDNESDAY
2022-01-19  3   WEDNESDAY
2022-01-26  3   WEDNESDAY
2022-02-02  3   WEDNESDAY
2022-02-09  3   WEDNESDAY
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```